# Migrating Wordpress media files to Google App Engine Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am attempting to migrate an existing wordpress site to Google App Engine. Following tutorials, I generally have it working via the standard app engine environment. However, there are thousands of media files that I'd like to migrate to a cloud bucket, and am stuck on what the best way is.

Google App Engine plugin for wordpress handles uploading to a Google Storage bucket and utilizes 'filter_directory' to redirect the media upload, but for old files, it seems tricky. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After trying to work this out, I ended up just manually copying the files to a new Google Cloud Bucket. [The Google Cloud Storage plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gcs/) filters the wp_upload directory and points to the cloud bucket. It generally worked